# Clear range, clear note(AudioKit : AKMusicTrack functions)

Tags: audiokit

I'm familiarizing myself with AKMusicTrack functions, specifically functions used to clear note data from a given sequence.

I can see that `clearRange()` will clear note data between a start and end range, and `clearNote()` will remove all events in the sequence of that note value.

Does anyone know of a function that will clear a single note? As in something like `clearSingleNote(noteNumber MIDINoteNumber, position AKDuration, end AKDuration)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `getMIDINoteData()` to get an array of `AKMIDINoteData`, filter out the notes you don't want, then overwrite the music track using `replaceMIDINoteData()` with your filtered array:

```
// remove a C at timestamp 4.0
var trackData = myTrack.getMIDINoteData()
trackData = trackData.filter { $0.noteNumber =! 60 && 
                               $0.duration =! AKDuration(beats: 4.0) }
myTrack.replaceMIDINoteData(with: trackData)
```

There are more examples using `getMIDINoteData()` in the [MIDIFileEditAndSync](https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/tree/develop/Examples/iOS/MIDIFileEditAndSync) example project.

Answer (score 0):

Right way:

```
trackData = trackData.filter { 
    !($0.noteNumber == 60 && $0.duration == AKDuration(beats: 4.0))
}
```

Comment: Please provide some explanations with your code as well.